# How to display different messages during the click event of dynamic radio button in android

Tags: android, radio-button

I have tried to display different messages for each dynamic radio button but it's not working. Could you please help me in solving this?

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    final EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_no);

    findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            int number=Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
            addRadioButtons(number);
        }

    });


}
```

public void addRadioButtons(int number) {

```
    for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++) {
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
            rdbtn.setId((row * 2) + i);
            rdbtn.setText("Radio " + rdbtn.getId());
            ll.addView(rdbtn);
        }
        ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup)).addView(ll);
    }

}

public void onRadioButtonClick(View v) {
    RadioButton button = (RadioButton) v;
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        button.getText() + " was chosen.",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: please specify in a good way that what you are expecting?

Comment: For each click in the dynamic radio button i need to display different text messages.How can it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

After adding radio buttons to RadioGroup, set onCheckedChangeListener to RadiGroup.

Like:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup=((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup));
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    RadioButton button = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,button.getText() + " was chosen.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Don't implement onRadioButtonClick(View view).

Comment: get the RadioGroup object in onCreate only. In addRadioButtons() method rather than using ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup)), use the object what we get in onCreate()